# Can I apply for a UK visitor visa while I am on ICT visa in the UK?

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration, standard-visitor-visas, working-visas

I am currently on an ICT work visa in the UK which is ending soon, but I want to spend some more time with my boyfriend in the UK before going back to my home country, India.

Can I apply for a visit or tourist visa within the UK while on an ICT visa or I would have to travel back to India and apply from there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no route to apply for a Visitor visa from within the UK.  An application must be made while the applicant is outside the UK and to a post designated to accept such applications. You will have to return to India unless you can legally enter another jurisdiction and apply from there.

Source: V2.1 https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor-rules